# Excel IF multiple columns

Tags: excel, if-statement

Im working with a large excel questionnaire that i would like to simplify the data output for further evaluation. 
[image]

What I'm trying to make is an IF statement, so that if the X is in fueloil the P coloum will write Fueloil ect..

```
=IF(K2="X";K1)
```

However when I'm trying to add another IF statement excel returns VALUE. is IF the right way to go about this or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need IF for this at all. You can use an Index/Match combo formula as demonstrated in the screenshot below. The formula in cell P2 is copied down.

```
=INDEX($K$1:$O$1,MATCH("x",K2:O2,0))
```

In words: Find the "x" in the current row and return the value from row 1 of that column.

If your regional settings require semicolons to separate parameters in formulas, please use

```
=INDEX($K$1:$O$1;MATCH("x";K2:O2;0))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Works just as i hoped! Thanks a lot