# Using Excel Index and Match functions to return multiple results

Tags: excel-formula

I'm testing bacteria for the presence of five genes and would like to report the genotype (a list of the genes present). I have the genes listed in each column. If the gene is present in a sample it gets a 1 and if it's absent the input is 0.

[image: Example gene results]

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45344486/excel-if-multiple-columns) I used the following formula:

=INDEX($B$1:$H$1,MATCH(1,B2:H2,0))

It's only giving back the result for the first "1" it comes to. So if there are multiple genes present it only lists the first one.

How can I change the formula to include multiple results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need and array version of `TEXTJOIN()`(Office 365 or Later):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B2:$H2=1,$B$2:$H$2))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

Or concatenate many IF statements(All versions):

```
=MID(IF(B2=1,", "&$B$1,"")&IF(C2=1,", "&$C$1,"")&IF(D2=1,", "&$D$1,"")&IF(E2=1,", "&$E$1,"")&IF(F2=1,", "&$F$1,"")&IF(G2=1,", "&$G$1,"")&IF(H2=1,", "&$H$1,""),3,999)
```

---

If one does not have Office 365 one can use this UDF the mimics the TEXTJOIN and use the formula as above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: I must not have 365 or later. TEXTJOIN doesn't pop up as a usable formula in Excel for me. Darn it! I'll have to figure something else out. Thank you!

Comment: @Bonnie please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.